# C#: XSD of remote REST entry point keeps adding enums. How to stay current? dynamically?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

We imported an XSD into our C# (.NET 4.6.1) app, and it works great hitting the REST entry point that publishes the XSD.

But the folks who host this endpoint  keep revving the XSD and adding enums, and the C# XML parser on our side blows up when they send us an enum that is not in the VS generated namespace.

The namespace is generated by the VS XSD tool:

`// This source code was auto-generated by xsd, Version=4.6.81.0.`

And all the strings are in the generated cs.

The questions:

1. Instead of converting the XSD to C# statically (at dev time), can
   we bind to it dynamically (at run time), to make it easier to move
   to new XSDs? (just copy new XSD into our project and run....)
2. How can I make my app (well, the .NET XML deserializer, I guess),
   skip unknown enums instead of blowing up?

In VS 2015, .NET 4.6.1

Comment: You can cast the enum to an integer so you don't have to declare every enum.

Comment: You mean ignore the string, enum? But where would we do that. We use the XSD compiler "// This source code was auto-generated by xsd, Version=4.6.81.0."  -- how would we go about casting to int?

Comment: @jdweng OP enhanced